# A simple regex call to replace some text in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need help with a really simple regex find/replace command for Eclipse. It'd be great if you could provide me with something to try.

I need to replace all occurrences of the text `typeSingleton(*) )`, with `typeSet({ * } )`.

Comment: What kind of characters you have inside brackets? The ones you replaced with `*`.

Comment: the characters could be the following: SomeWord( ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that inside brackets you may have letters, brackets, spaces, then:

Find: `typeSingleton\(([a-z ]+(\([a-z ]+\))? ?)\)`

Replace: `typeSet({$1})`

**EDIT**

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dD0wK0/1

Comment: It does the job, but not quite there yet... In instances where I would have: yieldType( typeSingleton( Num( ) ) ), the above regex search returned: yieldType( typeSet( {Num( ) } ). As you can see, it is missing the last paranthesis. I realized that this can be explained because it considers one of the parenthesis as simply another letter to replace.

Comment: Hate to have to keep bugging, but now the replaced text is missing one of the inner closing paranthesis. i.e. replaced text looks: typeSet({Num(}).

Comment: No worries, I;ve updated pattern again, should work now)